# USB error is very odd

Tags: usb, virtualbox

On Ubuntu 14.04 I installed VirtualBox and then
Windows XP Pro SP3.  Works really well.
Last night after work I booted up and all looked good.
Put in a Sandisk Cruiser.  Ubuntu doesn't see it.
Not even a light. Tried another, same brand. No go.
Tried a third and it worked fine. Tried a 4th of a different
brand, and it worked fine as usual. 5th one won't work.
All worked before. Tried everything I could find.
Non-working sticks work OK in real Windows machine.
Repeated tests. Still there's 2 that work and 3 that don't.
Same USB socket. Ubuntu simply sees only certain select
USB drives. USB keyboard and mouse are fine (through a
KVM switch shared with the real Windows machine).
Folders that seemingly should have files / info are empty.
If I only use the tried-and-true sticks, I'm golden.
Anyone have this problem??

PS I failed to emphasize that these dead sticks were working
just fine the day before. I didn't change anything on them.
They just won't light up. The physical port is the same one
I've been using for years.  Suddenly there's nothing, but only
on select sticks. Others light up just fine. Dead sticks work
fine in my Windows machine. All my sticks are formatted FAT 32.

Comment: What are the disks formatted as? When you plug them in to the machine do they show up in `lsblk`?

Comment: If they aren't lighting up it's possible something is interfering with the power to the stick. (Dust, or a damaged contact inside the stick would do it.) This sounds like a hardware problem. Check the USB filters on the VM as well.

Answer (score 0):

something that i tried recently was formatting a 32GB flashdrive as exFAT. im still playing with it to get it to mount. as i understand its just a matter of a few packages i need.

linux can SEE the drive perfectly fine it just can not mount the drive.

in fact if you go into a terminal and type

```
sudo lsblk
```

then you may see your drive listed there.

if you want to find out more about your disk that isnt showing up then you can use commands like

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

if you want to try and mount your drive that isnt automatically mounting then try creating a temp folder in /media to mount it to.

```
sudo mkdir /media/tmp
sudo mount /dev/sdXX /media/tmp
```

where /dev/sdXX is your drive you are trying to mount like /dev/sdc1